# Tags tab: find tag wildcards

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

I am looking to find tags that contain two words, order agnostic.
Say I want tags that have `.net` and `ajax`:

- When searching *"ajax .net"*, I get only [ajax.net](/questions/tagged/ajax.net),
- When searching *".net ajax"*, I get only [asp.net-ajax](/questions/tagged/asp.net-ajax).
- And most importantly I **NEVER** get [asp.net-mvc-ajax](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-ajax) by querying these 2 words.

I would like the query to be order insensitive, and if possible add wildcards.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: There is another question which asks to do the opposite, i.e. only/first suggest tags which *begin* with the keyword. Can't find it right now though.